What are linguistic concepts that are not widely applicable outside European languages?
Most linguists are familiar with European languages, and then may have also studied some Eurasian languages that are familiar to Europeans such as Japanese and varieties of Chinese. So it may be that linguistic descriptions of various morphosyntactic features are biased to a European perspective and unhelpful cross-linguistically.
I've read that the concept of finiteness of a verb is such an example, being most appropriate for Indo-European languages (and the typologically rather similar Uralic languages) that make a clear distinction between finite and nonfinite forms, while in various other languages the distinction is not clear or helpful to make.
What are other examples of potentially Eurocentric concepts that are used to analyse languages where such concepts may not be relevant?

Note that European and Indo-European are not the same thing. Finiteness is relevant to nearly all Indo-European languages, many of which are spoken outside Europe (e.g., Indic languages). It’s also relevant to various other language families spoken outside Europe, such as Semitic, Turkic, Quechuan, etc. Conversely, it’s not relevant to the only two non-Indo-European language you actually mention, Chinese and Japanese (or at least, it works very differently in Japanese than generally in Indo-European).

One example is noun classes mapped to gender.  With the exception of various Indo-Aryan languages, which are related to European languages, and Semitic languages, which arguably form a sort of Sprachbund with Indo-European languages, languages outside of Europe (and non-Indo-European languages indigenous to or introduced to Europe) tend to have either no gender, or many diverse noun classes.  Whereas most Indo-European languages of Europe have it.

Relative pronouns are very rare outside Europe.

These comments would make good answers!

The concept of standard average European might be a good starting point.

I think saying Eurocentric could be tendentious...
